# Find a tranformed matrix considering linear map and bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let matrix $A:= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
             2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$
And consider the linear map $L$ (restricted to A) : $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $x \rightarrow Ax$ with respect to the standard basis \begin{array}{c c c} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  & \text{and} &\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{array} for $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

Find the transformed matrix $T$ such that the same map can be expressed as $LA : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $ \rightarrow Tx$ with respect to the non-standard basis \begin{array}{c c c} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  & \text{and} &\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{array} for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (use this non-standard basis on both sides of the arrow, domain and codomain)

Here I have no idea how to proceed. I tried drawing a matrix transformation and computing the transformed map T with respect to vectors and bases and the known matrix A however I am not sure this is the correct way. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{bmatrix} $...  Then $B=P^{-1}AP$ will be the matrix of the linear transformation expressed in the new basis...

I get $\begin{bmatrix} 2 &1\\3&2\end{bmatrix}$...

Comment: Thank you. B in this case is T, right?  What does it mean to express the same map L(A) : Rˆ2 -> Rˆ2, x -> T.x   –  what does x stand for? A vector?

Comment: Yes.  $x$ is a vector and $A$ and $B$ are the matrices of $T$ relative to different bases...

Comment: Your notation above is a little confused...,  e.g. "$L$ restricted to $A$ " is meaningless,  i think...

Comment: What you want,  i think,  is that $A$ is the matrix of the linear transformation $L$ relative to the standard basis...  Also, $L$ and $T$ are the same transformations...

Comment: T = 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Did you get the same for T?

Comment: @user507945  See my edit, please...  I changed it to $P^{-1}AP$...  My answer is there.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same result after the edit.